# NoClassDefFoundError ObjenesisStd on Android API 19

Tags: android, mockito, dexmaker

I'm getting the following crashing during an instrumentation test ONLY on emulators running API v19. If I run on newer versions everything works fine.

> 03-01 20:26:18.781 2878-2878/? E/MonitoringInstrumentation: Exception
>   encountered by: Thread[main,5,main]. Dumping thread state to outputs
>   and pining for the fjords.
>                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.(ClassImposterizer.java:36)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.(ClassImposterizer.java:29)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.isTypeMockable(MockCreationValidator.java:17)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:21)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:133)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:127)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:50)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
>                                                                   at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)

The problem is this line:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.objenesis.ObjenesisStd

My app is multi-dex, and I'm using dexmaker-mockito for androidTestCompile. I'm at a complete loss why this only breaks on an older API. It started happening when I added another module to my project, which is a pure java module with no dependency on mockito.

Answer (score 0):

This exception (*ClassNotFoundException*) tells you about a **unmet** dependency at runtime: the JVM needs to load a class; which is not present in the class path.

Here it is Mockito that needs [Objenesis](http://objenesis.org/). Normally that library should be pulled automatically when you a system like maven and give the correct dependency to Mockito.

Comment: Objenesis is list in the dependency tree for androidTestCompile when I output the dependencies via Gradle. What's really odd is that this only happens on Android API v19 devices and below.